# Doesn't wait for web browser the navigate in for loop and loop finishes

Tags: c#

I want to click a button and have it take me to a page and I'll get its Url. After that it has to click to a radio button and the button on the same page. Clicking works fine but as you see in the code, it is in a for loop. That is why it doesn't wait for web browser to navigate. It keeps going and finishes the loop.

I have tried Timer but timer doesn't do the tick work. How can I do this?

```
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load(xmlPath);
        List<string> ListSs = new List<string>();
        XmlNodeList ilValuesList = xmldoc.SelectNodes("//*[@class='il']");

        List<string> ilLinkList = new List<string>();
        int sayac = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < kategoriler.Length; i++)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode item in ilValuesList)
            {
                string ilAdi = item.Name;
                string ilValue = item.Attributes["value"].Value;

                foreach (HtmlElement hElement in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
                {
                    if(hElement.GetAttribute("value").Equals(ilValue))
                    {
                        hElement.InvokeMember("click");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                foreach (HtmlElement hElementButton in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a"))
                {
                    if (hElementButton.GetAttribute("id").Equals("btnSearch"))
                    {
                        hElementButton.InvokeMember("click");
                        break;
                    }
                }

                ListSs.Add(webBrowser1.Url.ToString());
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < ListSs.Count; j++)
            {
                string xPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\XMLDosyalari" + kategoriXml[i];
                XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xPath);
                xdoc.Element("Hepsi").Add(new XElement(ilValuesList[j].Name, new XAttribute("value", ilValuesList[j].Attributes["value"].Value), new XAttribute("url", webBrowser1.Url.ToString())));
                xdoc.Save(xPath);
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried this in the `DocumentCompleted` event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, If you couldn't do it like me, you can try this;

```
   private void il_url_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (HtmlElement item in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
        {
            if (item.GetAttribute("value").Equals(IlValuesList[sayac].Attributes["value"].Value))
            {
                item.InvokeMember("click");
                break;
            }
        }

        foreach (HtmlElement item in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a"))
        {
            if (item.GetAttribute("id").Equals("btnSearch"))
            {
                item.InvokeMember("click");
                break;
            }
        }

        linkCek = true;
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (linkCek)
        {
            if (e.Url == webBrowser1.Url)
            {
                if (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                    return;
                else
                {
                    string path = Application.StartupPath + "\\XMLDosyalari" + kategoriXml[0];
                    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);
                    xdoc.Element("Hepsi").Add(new XElement(IlValuesList[sayac].Name, new XAttribute("class", "il"), new XAttribute("value", IlValuesList[sayac].Attributes["value"].Value), new XAttribute("url", webBrowser1.Url.ToString())));
                    xdoc.Save(path);

                    sayac++;
                    il_url_btn.PerformClick();
                }
            }
            else { return; }
        }
        else { }
    }
```